# Do I need amazon-cognito-identity-js if I already have the aws-sdk (javascript)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have a javascript project where I use the aws-sdk. No I want to use [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js). On the page it says:

> Note that the Amazon Cognito AWS SDK for JavaScript is just a slimmed down version 
>   of the AWS Javascript SDK namespaced as AWSCognito instead of AWS. It
>   references only the Amazon Cognito Identity service.

and indeed, I can for example create CognitoIdentityServiceProvider with:

```
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
```

But how do I do thinks like authenticate a user? According to the [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) documentation:

```
authenticationDetails = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails({Userame: ..., Password: ...});
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, ...)
```

But the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider object does not have a AuthenticationDetails property.

Do I have to do something different when I use the aws-sdk instead of amazon-cognito-identity-js?

Or is my assumption wrong, and I need both, the aws-sdk and amazon-cognito-identity-js?

Comment: You need both; the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html) (or just the [Amazon Cognito AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/master/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js)) in addition to [Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945187/3770040) answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't. You can login using aws-sdk like this:

```
const cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ region });
cognito.adminInitiateAuth({
  AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
  ClientId: clientId,
  UserPoolId: poolId,
  AuthParameters: {
    USERNAME: email,
    PASSWORD: password,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi JakubM, i tried this solution, but getting error - 'CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config'. Can you please help me here?

Comment: Well, I guess you don't have AWS credentials set? Look to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Comment: Is there any way to avoid accessKeyId and secretAccessKey?

Comment: It depends where you run the code and what's your use case. If it is in AWS environment like Lambda then you don't need them. If it runs client-side in browsers you can use Cognito Identity. I believe all available approaches should be described on the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

For userName password authentication, it needs to have ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH.
I also added function to handle err and success. For more details about response and token sent in data, you can check was reference.

```
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    cognito.adminInitiateAuth({
        AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        ClientId: 'clientId',
        UserPoolId: 'poolId'
        AuthParameters: {
            USERNAME: 'userName',
            PASSWORD: 'password',
        },
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for any coming in the future

the following is what i did for register and login using

```
    private cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
```

- register:

  ```
  public async register(event) {

   try {

       if(!this.validator.isObjectNotEmpty(event.body)){                
           throw new Error("you have to include body to insert into DB !!");
       }

       const usermodel = event.body;
       if (this.validator.isEmailNotValid(usermodel)) {
           throw new Error("Not Valid username or password");
       }

       const email = usermodel.email.toLowerCase();
       const password = usermodel.password;

       const createUserParams = {
           UserPoolId: Cognito_User_Pool, // From Cognito dashboard 'Pool Id'
           Username: email,
           MessageAction: "SUPPRESS", // Do not send welcome email
           TemporaryPassword: password,
       };

       const user = await this.cognito.adminCreateUser(createUserParams).promise();
       this.logger.info("created user: ",user);

       const initiateAuthParams = {
           AuthFlow: "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
           ClientId: Cognito_User_Pool_Client,
           UserPoolId: Cognito_User_Pool,
           AuthParameters: {
               USERNAME: email,
               PASSWORD: password
           }
       };
       const challengesResponse = await this.cognito.adminInitiateAuth(initiateAuthParams).promise();
       this.logger.info("challengesResponse: ",challengesResponse);

       const userPasswordParams = {
           Password: password,
           UserPoolId: Cognito_User_Pool,
           Username: email,
           Permanent: true
       };

       return this.cognito.adminSetUserPassword(userPasswordParams).promise();

   } catch (error) {
       console.log("error: ", error);
       throw error;
   }
  }
  ```

---

- login

  ```
  public async login(event) {
   try {

       this.logger.info("login - event: ",JSON.stringify(event));
       this.logger.info("register - Cognito_User_Pool: ",Cognito_User_Pool);
       this.logger.info("register - Cognito_User_Pool_Client: ",Cognito_User_Pool_Client);

       if(!this.validator.isObjectNotEmpty(event.body)){                
           throw new Error("you have to include body to insert into DB !!");
       }

       const usermodel = event.body;
       if (this.validator.isEmailNotValid(usermodel)) {
           throw new Error("Not Valid username or password");
       }

       const email = usermodel.email.toLowerCase();
       const password = usermodel.password;

       const initiateAuthParams = {
           AuthFlow: "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
           ClientId: Cognito_User_Pool_Client,
           UserPoolId: Cognito_User_Pool,
           AuthParameters: {
               USERNAME: email,
               PASSWORD: password
           }
       };
       return await this.cognito.adminInitiateAuth(initiateAuthParams).promise();
   } catch (error) {
       console.log("error: ", error);
       throw error;
   }
  }
  ```

the login function return response like this:

```
   "tokenObj": {
    "ChallengeParameters": {},
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "eyJraWQiOiI1ZFN5R0tEUFE2WnhTbzJ4N01QTXpxaVRPNXZoK3p5NkJaOFZhRzV1M0Z3PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.4vswc6-ei6SFlbN0k_C8PAtmEK294oFfylYZW3hhmHqMT49d_JWdDPR8XgA7n5cLqtLJsiG4PVh9SyxdirpUTmC0yra2GZejNWP8eVHG9-JUq_xXQ81a8AYEb1KZJBAv0j2F1ZLuCFaiFvbOBFEGSlJXp4e2bLz-NWlSbEAUbxZV5BKrRmZEeXJUxw_DO5R30SG1D2qcOn_1mnbdfTH-W0ZMuuMJsHWQBsO7QEtyMI62XG35WRDijzzMr6ekbLyIQ7J77dYcsmTdR6S5nTNWE1yrGYtkdxk2x35nYob06PAWdnWL5OK2G1aiJ97BMvM65VtjX8VQZbAoalIII-PbCA",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "TokenType": "Bearer",
        "RefreshToken": "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.FKN-KM415xH-TioTkKjmoy_NV1AssBq9GlkweHAK7TuYzMeI_qMfeL00Qv6MiOPFMJ6UG7cLKfJjkdyI1vK09p9lk5_wor3FoCX1Dvt3DK3SKzeyqW6ULQL1IQmNunPhpC3sARom0q74YxSaQKdF_6PgDjNnf0-aI1XGkZYZUw69BZGQDVobTx8nR_Lf6srF622s0JuhaClDfvIgqjZun7AIFlxgNUKL6uuMgmSrRJm7GvAqAnTQpmQD2sdz6D3fWeoVja8LRpc_QMbZPhjZmOoRrQJ3VA-m0M0TsNMvQSw6px-WS-hMUH4RFeFasrbmoiUKIU8-MXltyPVltoy0qg.dHBgjs1NAOAROzD6.vi7DzrqzLkuHGuuGY1vNZaYmdDp0-EliwxTtEOaMboVlMCm9KZv0tU06ovQ9Z2CbplqJdEaAu-YZSG3Oeagqj5JJ2-739C0yvA0J_qE2Ehn5gCUMuiPPOjakIczOcI8wcRItsTGqt1GFmyq4DSnX-pjc9GG2QWpgmcsoDyxodIv1wTu7YN15cGK0YN_xSKolcCn04gCzqXCDkQyUqX-Sr7QqD2o-aQC1ynmKz1tJGxRM3I6rzbcRZkNvUK02wSIUMeY05hJNAdKBItIE0t45Sk5_EV3mzLgebC39Q6z-kRKNQwhyQKrcXg71aRJGjD3HH61VEoops4wcgRCmNnI7u-9JjJic_SDU_Fw-9W1L8BxZZKPsJrjOvJroDFc1xX2njgeivo6ZpRWTg3nQphMTqJFSYHnWcEmw3EW1uUhN7e1J2bdGuebW40Opf5zMXo2V4-OBI3UMxTOVZEPit4g3yLDHQDAfPZllPPRf5H8Kf1Qe54fEq77sKb32I5PH7t-7xQ79iE5KX6BZjsLjwHMAlGNtS7WSE-U0yAsjUFFH8pA7eYR5ysz3o9L7jJsNCyNb06YU_QX5mozGlspLMNs4qpUcWkFGhSNG6qTRMREpzRfELU82Dc-LirJ1425zPQNsQV1CGGtlDoXVA-RCIgnMG1hslfpIllKm_IH-5yyPMfH2UFdr7jdRjt9crFyFu9ktGkHjnAqH_ZUcueL0q_vrIqmkGcBcrQQRY9jCSC4VNeGhKe9ecJciAHUCktkZuut5yI0De0hXANoaoxeIucJlox57nxHnQTD0Q0LEuXvfqG9M9sNdB4GGrt1rYR58ZWa8zc5udoKDMxvrb6GEeDI1co2mLEt3XghjcJBJqB8nqwofXZDxiDSXQ53R9L5U8wDlxhxZxPMDKFL6wu4gqDjw4m60R8mOvfOI2Gz_yelqfk5CxD6Ts_HVbv9TRbsV0adQ4S8n5Cktf5miWUtFCOktruS2_fKfB6TF1yzisgxQpJFD7B1qdTcBu0N82KgHrljoBlVKiwGdalL52H-cJkNkagZIBQYXvlvkBrbsSNAp1CeUiqXbddHku47RNjXSPUMN1aoHdEL14_7zbaPYBMxgEsmqjP67B45QKmTyDDsOkf8aSdAWYFKvj3c_4Cn_LczLU-YcuzE4UZvd6BQK70MiKBIsd3DU4rdKTDjAsN73mJ_U-_8r34jocny4rzbO_NostPjgqUugoO2bGhfr_PUgXb7sm_wrKlvjFnUcOLpQSBxlZL_z25e8vZokRn4QiNa83_VG6xyp77-c_DQqLC3RdwXOyRmCEXkM2D10cBNQpkAzCBMyP9FO3mJZcQ.aAJlWM76hqlRprKY8P_Qmw",
        "IdToken": "eyJraWQiOiJoWmpBMXl1d2JjT1lyNks5dnhQc2ZKVDhXSHRrYm51WmZlTURlK0dBbWR3PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.L9nNSlcQakRfVpAo-bf9jnXFrhov8iD9j3R2UI7x5eUT42OBrvSdEk3Y2JtFKQt1FpxBFLqtWCRyY0Wxlcq3MzZE04zIFBC02WmV24vF1QS9TxpBYAm8NkyNoW-7Lqe7CIWhK_DHMxSRpzo87txmwpID6xwd9JOlZG04L76hkXr0_2JgM2KuvB0lKL0v4heHK8e2ht_VuKBPNpVvMIbIA2xN22LRhivfG8EMeHmF3jhhQYggi1Pczb2WEviPUqebmLhdvjJpHC9OMVhvN4GMcr0JVv-GepxSCrNSFoXPDNZaznJbDJW0Zt3xY9bWek_l62v1Wm0a1h7V7nxw8a0Csw"
        }
    }
}
```