# AWSCognito in Angular4 (SpaceFinder) Example

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'd like to understand the difference between

`AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);`

vs

`new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);`

Since most examples I've found use AWSCognito, and AWS declared similar to:

```
declare let AWS: any;
declare let AWSCognito: any;
```

or

```
declare const AWS: any;
declare const AWSCognito: any;
```

yet the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944933/awscognito-is-not-defined) and the document documentation propose a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

For script usage, the different objects are available on the AWSCognito object. And with webpack you can get them on the AWS object, similar to what the main AWS SDK does.

I think this solution works. ['AWSCognito' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944933/awscognito-is-not-defined)